# How can I use a fixed port for IEDriverServer.exe in Robot framework?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to open a web page using selenium and IEDriverServer. The issue is only specific ports are open. I need to run the driver executable on a specific port.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `--port` switch when starting the driver. You can see the available command switches [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#command-line-switches).

Comment: I am trying the most basic code as below:
Open Browser https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com:19100/web/login.jsp ie
Click Element id=overridelink
where do i append --port and switch. Sorry , i m very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Create Webdriver` keyword it is possible to set the port as a parameter:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
Custom IE WebDriver port

    Create Webdriver    Ie   port=${7777}
    Go to     http://cnn.com

    Close Browser
```